# Saving geotiff in R - why resolution on x and y is not the same?

Tags: r, geotiff-tiff, resolution

I have some data and i want to save it as a geotiff in R. This is not a problem but even if in my command line i set the resolution on x as 1 and on y as 1 after the geotiff is generated the resolution on x is 0.999 .... something instead on 1. Resolution on y is 1 as i set it previously. I saw same behavior in ArcGIS as well when i generate geotiffs form data. I am wondering why this happens.

Any explanation will be welcome.

PS. this time my raster in R has no projections - i have user define "coodinates" which can be considered metric.

Thanks,
Monica

OK here it is some generated data and the R code to generate the geotiff:

```
       set.seed(333)
    v1 <- rnorm(100, mean=0.23, sd=0.47)
    v2 <- rnorm(100, mean=0.17, sd=0.83)
    v3 <- rnorm(100, mean=0.34, sd=0.68)
    v4 <- rnorm(100, mean=0.59, sd=1.25)
    v5 <- rnorm(100, mean=-0.27, sd=0.91)
    v6 <- rnorm(100, mean=0.03, sd=1.37)
    test.m <- cbind(v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6)
    test.m <- t(test.m)
    r2a <- raster(test.m, xmn=1, xmx=dim(test.m)[2], ymn = 1, ymx=7, crs=NA)
    r2a

    class       : RasterLayer 
    dimensions  : 6, 100, 600  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
    resolution  : 0.99, 1  (x, y)
    extent      : 1, 100, 1, 7  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
    coord. ref. : NA 
    data source : in memory
    names       : layer 
    values      : -3.397683, 4.136409  (min, max)
```

So, i expected to have resolution 1 x 1 and not 0.99 x 1. It is not really a big deal in the large scheme of things for what i am doing but i have to recognize - i am very curious why.

Thanks again,

Monica

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your R code so we can recreate the issue and thus, provide a relevant solution. As it is we can only speculate.

Comment: There is any way i can attach a table for data? I am new here and i am not sure how i can do that ..... The R code is very straight forward and i doubt is the mistake there .... maybe the data have something to do with it. Monica.

Comment: OK, solved the problem by generating some data.

Comment: Your problem is not reproducible: the value of `r2a` is not what you have posted. In any event, by stipulating the output extent, you have implicitly specified both the horizontal and vertical resolution, because the x extent has to be divided into `dim(test.m)[1]` equal pieces and the y extent into `dim(test.m)[2]` equal pieces. Unless you arrange to make the resolutions equal, of course they must differ!

Comment: Sorry, i see, i forgot one line of code .... i will add it to the main post. What i forgot is to make again test.m <- t(test.m) .... and now r2a should be correct. So i have 100 columns and i gave the extent from 1 to 100 and 6 rows with extent from 1 to 7, so i should have resolution 100/100 and 6 / 6 for x and respectively y resolution for my raster. Monica

Answer (score 1):

A friend of mine gave the answer. In R - and probably other software - the coordinates are the top left and bottom right of the raster extent and they do not start with the center of the cell. So if my coordinates for x axis are between 1 to 100 and i have 100 rows then i do have only 99 cells available in which i have to cram 100 values, so 99/100 = 0.99 which is my resolution on x. On Y, by chance, i had the coordinates correct, from 1 to 7 for 6 rows so .... 6 / 6 =1.

That explains the mystery ;-)

Monica